# Add column in pandas with strings and floats

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe. Trying to add a recommendation column based on the data each record. Getting strange output. See below. Any help would be appreciated.

```
df =
name    sales   performance vs goal
jane    110     0.1
john    120     0.2
```

want:

```
name    sales   performance vs goal     recommendation
jane    110     0.1                     sales 0.1 above goal
john    120     0.2                     sales 0.2 above goal
```

code:

```
df['recommendation'] = 'sales ' + str(df['performance vs goal']) + ' above goal'
```

getting:

```
 name    sales   performance vs goal     recommendation
 jane    110     0.1                     sales 0.1\n24 above goal
 john    120     0.2                     sales 0.1\n24 above goal
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `str(df[...])` you convert the Series to a string, you don't get a Series of strings. Do this instead:

```
df['recommendation'] = 'sales ' + df['performance vs goal'].astype(str) + ' above goal'
```

Alternatively (arguably more elegant, but probably slower):

```
df['performance vs goal'].apply("sales {} above goal".format)
```

Answer (score 2):

instead of writing it like you have below you can consider using any other string interpolation approach.
so don't use this

```
df['recommendation'] = 'sales ' + str(df['performance vs goal']) + ' above goal'
```

but use this.

```
performance_vs_goal = df['performance vs goal']
df['recommendation']= "sales %s above goal" % (performance_vs_goal)
```

so what I did was to store the performance goal as variable and the use string interpolation. you can decide not to store it in a variable first but I feel it is readable.

so what the solution does is to replace %s with your new value. so it is like a placeholder

you can even take it a step further by storing above or below as a variable that changes based on value.

e.g.

```
performance_vs_goal = df['performance vs goal']
if performance_vs_goal >= 0.1:
   df['recommendation'] = "sales %s above goal" % (performance_vs_goal)
else:
    df['recommendation']= "sales %s less than goal" % (performance_vs_goal)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension while iterating over the values of the `performance vs goal` column, and use f-strings to more easily see the output:

```py
df["recommendation"] = [f"sales {value} above goal" for value in df["performance vs goal"]]
```